# Dynamic Programming Task in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic-programming

Here is a toy version of a DP problem I am trying to solve. Let's say that we have two neighborhoods with 2 and 3 parking-stations, respectively.

1. Each parking-station has a capacity that ranges from 0 to a fixed positive number.
2. The state of the system at any given time instant is the available parking spots of the stations. For example, (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) where (2, 3) refer to the available spots of the stations in the first neighborhood and (4, 5, 6) in the second neighborhood.
3. Each station can be on (1) or off (0), and we wish to find what stations to turn on or off in each state. Towards this we have to test all possible on/off combinations. One such combination for the above setting would be [ [0,1], [1,0,1] ].
4. Last, there are the positive probabilities of traveling from each station in a departure neighborhood to a destination neighborhood. For example, λ_{1,2}^{2} is the probability of going from station 2 in neighborhood 1 to neighborhood 2.

What I need help with is how I should store the above things to make life easier and how to code the computation of the state values. The states you can transition to from a current state are conditioned on the lambdas probabilities and the given recommendation. For example, for the state (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and the recommendation [ [0,1], [1,0,1] ], the value would be:

[image]

- Explanation of the first term: Given this lambda, we have that the car leaves from station 1 in neighborhood 1 to go to neighborhood two. Hence, the state of station 1 in neighborhood 1 goes from 2 to 3. Moreover, we have two recommended stations in neighborhood 2, where the car can equally likely go to. Therefore,  we get two terms. In the first, the capacity of station 1 in neighborhood 2 drops by 1 and in the second term the capacity of station 3 in neighborhood 2 drops by 1.

  - Similar explanation for the second term, with the only difference that the car now leaves from station 2 in neighborhood 1.
  - For the third term, we see from the lambda that the car goes from station 1 in neighborhood 2 to neighborhood 1. But now, only the second station of neighborhood 1 is recommended and hence we only get one term where the capacity of station 2 in neighborhood 1 drops by 1 and that of station 1 in neighborhood 2 increases by 1.
  - Similar explanations for the other terms.

The general pseudocode of the problem that I have in my mind:

```
 Create State_Space
 Create recommendation_combinations # All possible (0,1) combinations 
 V = dict([state,0] for state in State_Space) # Initialize the value vector

for each_state in State_Space:
   for each_recommendation_combination in recommendation_combinations:
       Compute V(state)_combination

   V(state) = min(V(state)_combination)
```

Given the complexity of the problem's structure (i.e. stations inside neighborhoods), how would you recommend to store the above? (I was thinking to use dictionaries, but I don't know how to use itertools with dictionaries to create the recommendation combinations). Moreover, any programming help for the state's value computation greatly is appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to explain the problem quite a bit more. What is a station? (Subway stations? Gas stations? Electrical sub-stations?) What relation does a station have to its neighborhood and what does it mean if it's "turned off"? Who is "traveling" and what does that mean for the stations/neighborhoods/capacities?

Comment: You can think of it as parking-stations inside some neighborhoods, and each parking-station has a fixed number of parking spots. Turned off would me that the parking station is full or close to capacity. Traveling: There is always one car traveling and it can go from any neighborhood to any neighborhood. The lambda is telling you where he goes from which starting destination/neighborhood. I will add some more description about the terms in my above equation.

Comment: What is V exactly. A unitless probability?

Comment: Can a car travel within the neighborhood?

Comment: "we wish to find what stations to turn on or off in each state". I still find this very unclear.

Comment: Please show an actual computation for the example you show here.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Dynamic programming is a technique to efficiently solve optimization problems with [optimal substructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure).  What are you trying to optimize here?  It looks like you might actually be trying to model a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), which is a different type of problem.